# django-grappelli not working

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I am unable to get [django-grappelli](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/) working. 
Below is what I did -

1. Installed using `pip install django-grappelli`.
2. Added '`grappelli`' in **INSTALLED_APPS** before the '`django.contrib.admin`' .
3. In urls.py, added URL definition `url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls'))`, before admin url, ie. `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`
4. Executed `syncdb` and `collectstatic` commands.

Now when I run command runserver, and browse *localhost:8000/admin/*, surprisingly I am getting the default admin.

I checked the request traffic in Google Chrome Network tab (in Developers Tool), and I don't see any request for url starting with Grappelli.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am using Django 1.4.1-final in virtualenv on Windows 7 machine.

Comment: You are using virtualenv, so have you activated it before making `pip install`?

Comment: Yes, i have activated it before install. I always work inside the vietualenv. Also, I have installed Yolk package, which shows the installed packages and their installation dir in virtualenv. I can also see the django-grapelli in venv/lib/site-packages/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue. Actually I had previously overridden the Admin Templates for branding my admin login and top page headers. So, in my template dir, there is admin dir with some custom templates (which I copied from `django/contrib/admin/templates` and edited as per my requirement). Due to this, Grappelli was not showing any of my changes...

I got the hint from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12193858/1284552

When I removed it, it worked as expected.
Also, I just need to visit the admin path, not the grappelli path as defined in Urls.py.

Answer (score 6):

Resolved this issue after adding `'grappelli'` at the top of `'django.contrib.admin'`.

Adding to Lucian's answer, the documentation itself says,

Insert `'grappelli'` at the top of `'django.contrib.admin'`.

So `INSTALLED_APPS` will be,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Taken from : http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing, I changed the order of the rows and all earned

'grappelli',

'django.contrib.admin',

make sure that the string 'django.contrib.admin' written 1 times